# Mysql and Perl using INTERVAL to calculate a total

Tags: mysql, perl, date, intervals

Thank you for an example. I'm a trouble to figure out a statement with interval...
I need calculate users in certain interval of dates, but  interval must be entered by a user. Example: from '2010/05/05' to '2010/30/07' if interval is 1m(month), then total of this users each 1m interval, like this:  2010/05/05 to 2010/06/05 is total users.
So far I got:

```
SELECT col1, client, COUNT(client) FROM table1, table2 WHERE col1 IN (condition) AND  date BETWEEN '2010/05/01' AND '2010/07/30' AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL + 1  month) GROUP BY client;
```

Of course it calculates all total, but not dates with interval.

Also I tried to use Perl

```
my @data; #data from dbase.
%date_hash = ($data[1] =>$total);  #$data[1] is beg and  end dates user entered 
foreach  $dates (values %date_hash) {
    $date_hash{$dates}=$total;   
    print "Print hash:  $dates        $date_hash{$dates} \n"
```

Thank you in advance,  :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible SQL only solution (I will offer an algorithm, not exact SQL code)

- Create a temp table `INTERVALS`, populate it (probably easiest to do from Perl in a loop, though MYSQL loop would be sufficient) with data as follows (from 5/5/2010 to 12/10/2010, 1 month intervals):

  ```
  | start_period | end_period | interval_number |
  ===============================================
  | 2010/05/05   | 2010/06/04 | 1               |
  | 2010/06/05   | 2010/07/04 | 2               |
  | ...
  | 2010/12/05   | 2010/12/10 | 8               |
  ```
- Then, run the query joining your table to `INTERVALS` temp table via

  ```
   SELECT client, COUNT(client)
        , i.interval_number, i.start_period, i.end_period
   FROM table1 
   WHERE col1 IN (condition)
   AND table1.date >= inetrvals.start_period
   AND table1.date <= inetrvals.end_period
   GROUP BY client, i.interval_number, i.start_period, i.end_period
  ```

  Please note that you can select other columns from table1 but only if you group on them as well.